# Define ScheduledFargateTask to run a simple java program

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-event-bridge

I need to run a simple java program - that reads from an s3 bucket and deletes certain files - once an hour every hour. I initially did this in a scheduled lambda function but because the task takes longer than 15 minutes Lambda is no longer an option.

It seems a scheduled [Fargate task is a good alternative](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ScheduledFargateTask.html). I am defining the various AWS assets in a typescript CDK package. I have my java code in the same package and I'd like to define my scheduled Fargate task to execute this java file every hour - how can I do this?

When I defined the java lambda function it was very easy to specify the lambda should run this java file via:

```
.code(Code.fromAsset("../myJavaProgram.java"))
```

however I cannot find a scheduled Fargate task equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying an ECS task is a bit more complicated than deploying a Lambda function. You need to create a Dockerfile that defines how to build your Docker image, and get that running as a Docker container locally first. Only after you have the app successfully running in Docker locally should you proceed to deploying it on AWS.

After you have it running in Docker, you would create an image repository in AWS ECR, and push the image to that repository. Finally, you would tell the CDK to use that image by referencing it via `ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry` as shown in the documentation you linked to in your question.

Comment: You don't need to create an ECR repo and push to it, you can just use `ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset` and CDK will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When using ECS (or any container orchestrator for that matter) there is one more step in your development process, which is to define a container image (ie, Dockerfile). The nice thing about the AWS CDK is you don't have to define your own build/push scripts to a container registry as it can handle the build, push, and referencing of that image all within the CDK app.

I would recommend leveraging the aws-ecs-patterns library with the [ScheduledFargateTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ScheduledFargateTask.html) construct. This will get you up and running much faster to solve your problem.

Example:

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Vpc', { maxAzs: 1 });
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'EcsCluster', { vpc });
const scheduledFargateTask = new ecsPatterns.ScheduledFargateTask(this, 'ScheduledFargateTask', {
  cluster,
  scheduledFargateTaskImageOptions: {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('amazon/amazon-ecs-sample'),
    memoryLimitMiB: 512,
  },
  schedule: appscaling.Schedule.expression('rate(1 minute)'),
  tags: [
    {
      key: 'my-tag',
      value: 'my-tag-value',
    },
  ],
});
```

Now, in regards to building your Docker image I would recommend keeping it simple. There are container images available that are scoped to a specific language (ie, Java) that come pre-baked with all of the necessary software for your code to run while you simply provide the code and dependencies. Here's an example image you could try getting started with: https://gallery.ecr.aws/amazoncorretto/amazoncorretto